Can I make Pandas joins of data frames more concise?
I'm trying to create a function that allows a user to bring in a list of over/unders and then joins this list to a series of projection systems to see how it may compare (i.e. a player's over/under for hits will be compared to projected hits from six different projection systems). The problem I'm running into is that I don't want my code to be repeating steps depending on the over/under type that a user chooses; I want to make it more concise/versatile.
The logic I have with the function currently is that there are three different inputs a user can choose (hits, home runs, rbis). For each input there's an if statement (which I've included in the example below), within each if statement I need to subset the over/under data frame by parameter selection (in the example below that is hits), then join to all six projection data frames (while sub selecting only relevant fields), and then calculating the average from all of the projection system for the parameter selection.
Is there any way to give my code the ability to do the above steps based on the initial parameter selection (instead of writing all of below out again two more times), knowing that the fields I will be joining from each of the projection data frames will differ based on parameter (i.e. instead of h_pecota_50 it will be rbi_pectoa_50 if RBI is the parameter selected)? I feel like some sort of for loop might be possible, but not sure the structure of it or if this strategy even makes the most sense. Apologies for the long-windedness, any advice would be appreciated.
if investment_type_sub.lower() == 'hits':
        
        #Select columns (IDs) that will need to join to projections (BPID, IDFANGRAPHS, DAVENPORTID)
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hitting_ids[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU']]

        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections.query('Hits_OU > 0')

        #Join to BP 50th percentile
        #Merge PECOTA percentile datasets to the OU hits dataframe
        ou_hits_all_projections = pd.merge(ou_hits_all_projections, pecota_hitting_50, how = 'left', left_on='BPID', right_on='bpid_PECOTA_50')

        #Bring in only rows that you need for each projection system
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU','h_PECOTA_50']]

        #Join to BP 99th percentile
        #Merge PECOTA percentile datasets to the OU strikeouts dataframe
        ou_hits_all_projections = pd.merge(ou_hits_all_projections, pecota_hitting_99, how = 'left', left_on='BPID', right_on='bpid_PECOTA_99')

        #Bring in only rows that you need for each projection system
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU','h_PECOTA_50', 'h_PECOTA_99']]

        #Merge ZIPs dataset to the OU hits dataframe
        ou_hits_all_projections = pd.merge(ou_hits_all_projections, zips_hitting, how = 'left', left_on='IDFANGRAPHS', right_on='PlayerId_ZIPs')

        #Bring in only rows that you need for each projection system
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU', 'h_PECOTA_50','h_PECOTA_99', 'H_ZIPs']]

        #Merge Steamer dataset to the OU hits dataframe
        ou_hits_all_projections = pd.merge(ou_hits_all_projections, steamer_hitting, how = 'left', left_on='IDFANGRAPHS', right_on='PlayerId_steamer')

        #Bring in only rows that you need for each projection system
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU', 'h_PECOTA_50','h_PECOTA_99', 'H_ZIPs', 'H_steamer']]

        #Merge the_bat dataset to the OU hits dataframe
        ou_hits_all_projections = pd.merge(ou_hits_all_projections, the_bat_hitting, how = 'left', left_on='IDFANGRAPHS', right_on='PlayerId_the_bat')

        #Bring in only rows that you need for each projection system
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU', 'h_PECOTA_50','h_PECOTA_99', 'H_ZIPs', 'H_steamer', 'H_the_bat']]

        #Merge the_bat dataset to the OU hits dataframe
        ou_hits_all_projections = pd.merge(ou_hits_all_projections, davenport_hitting, how = 'left', left_on='DAVENPORTID', right_on='HOWEID_davenport')

        #Bring in only rows that you need for each projection system
        ou_hits_all_projections = ou_hits_all_projections[['BPID','IDFANGRAPHS', 'DAVENPORTID', 'Player', 'Hits_OU', 'h_PECOTA_50','h_PECOTA_99', 'H_ZIPs', 'H_steamer', 'H_the_bat', 'H_davenport']]

        #Calculates the average for all projection systems in the relevant O/U field; try and eventually find a way to get what you dividing by an automatic calc
        ou_hits_all_projections['hit_avg'] = np.where((ou_hits_all_projections.Hits_OU > 0),
                                             ((ou_hits_all_projections.h_PECOTA_50+
                                               ou_hits_all_projections.h_PECOTA_99+
                                               ou_hits_all_projections.H_ZIPs
                                              +ou_hits_all_projections.H_steamer + ou_hits_all_projections.H_the_bat +
                                               ou_hits_all_projections.H_davenport))/
                                          ((len(ou_hits_all_projections.columns)-5)), 0)
        
        #Adds in field taking the % difference between the average and the O/U
        ou_hits_all_projections['hit_avg_diff'] = (ou_hits_all_projections['Hits_OU']-ou_hits_all_projections['hit_avg'])/(ou_hits_all_projections['Hits_OU'])
        
        return ou_hits_all_projections.sort_values('hit_avg_diff', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    


Given any back and forth would be limited here...I will make some assumptions.
Rather than viewing your dataframe (df) as being conditional, take the perspective of how an ETL solution would work.  Extract the data, your initial df, and work towards creating transformations of the original df to meet to meet the conditions.  Based on the satisfaction of the condition, you access the appropriate transformation.  In summary, remove the user input impact in order to drive conditions based on having the appropriate transformations of the original df to meet the result.
